# Establishing a minimum value for Javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I have a series of radio buttons on my page that, when checked, establish certain conditions. For each condition, a value is subtracted from the PRICE, which is the final variable that is provided to the user.

```
if (condition1==0){price-=5;}
if (condition2==1){price-=4;}       
if (condition3==1){price-=10;}
var minimum = 1;
if (price < minimum){price = minimum;)
```

The conditions are all working exactly as I want. For this code group, I basically don't want "price" to go below 1. My problem is that this is creating an error and I am really not sure why. I am more familiar with Java, so perhaps I am running into an error that Javascript throws that I am not familiar with.

What can I do to make sure that my "price" variable does not fall below my "minimum" variable, without throwing an error?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the variable name "minimum" with "minprice"? Just a hunch.

Comment: Telling us the error is vital in order to help

Comment: Please bring the error that shows up.

Comment: It's a simple typo, there should be a curly brace at the end of the last line, not a parentheses. i.e `if (price < minimum){price = minimum;}`

Comment: I can think of no reason that this shouldn't work, besides the fact that you have no closing curly brace around price=minimum :-/

Comment: It turns out I had minimum already used as a variable earlier, and it was a string. This was my mistake. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a parentheses `)` after `price = minimum;` rather than a curly bracket `}` which is why your code is creating an error.

Here is the changes.

Before:

```
if (price < minimum){price = minimum;)
```

After:

```
if (price < minimum){price = minimum;}
                                     ^
```

Comment: It turns out I had minimum already used as a variable earlier, and it was a string. This was my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
if (condition1 === 0) { price = Math.max(price - 5, 1); }
```

Or generalize it into a function:

```
function reducePriceBy(amount) {
    return Math.max(price - amount, 1); 
}
```

And then

```
if (condition1 === 0) { price = reducePriceBy(5); }
```

Comment: This is a good idea, since I will be using this function in many places.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a syntax error to start: `if (price < minimum){price = minimum;}`

The last parentheses should have been a brace.

Comment: It turns out I had minimum already used as a variable earlier, and it was a string. This was my mistake. Thank you.